# Get value of array to controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have code in view

```
  $(container).append('<div class="form-group">'+'<input type=text name="situs[]" class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' +
                        'placeholder="www.namasitus.com"' + iCnt + '" />');
```

in controller

```
    if (isset($_POST['situs']))
    {
    $array_domain = $_POST['situs'];
    foreach ($array_domain as $value) // loop array
    {
        $dataa = array(
        'situs' => $value
    );
    }   
    }
```

I just get 1 value (last value in array)
how solve this problem

Comment: you overwrite `$dataa` every iteration of the loop. maybe you meant `$dataa[] = ...`?

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting $dataa variable everytime.

```
if (isset($_POST['situs']))
{
    $dataa = [];
    $array_domain = $_POST['situs'];
    foreach ($array_domain as $value) // loop array
    {
        $dataa[] = ['situs' => $value];
    }
}
```

Try this.